# Changing model parameters by cPar in other module

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I am using this module hierarchy :

- `Node: {udpApp[0]<->udp<->networkLayer->wlan[0]} and wlan[0]: {CNPCBeacon<->mac<->radio}`

I have given some initial parameter in the `ini` file for `udpApp` as :

```
**.host*.numUdpApps = 2
**.host*.udpApp[0].typename = "UDPBasicApp" 
**.host*.udpApp[0].chooseDestAddrMode = "perBurst"
**.host*.udpApp[0].destAddresses = "gw1"
**.host*.udpApp[0].startTime = 1.32s
**.host*.udpApp[0].stopTime = 1.48s
```

But at run time I want to change the `startTime` and `stopTime` for `udpAPP[0]` through `CNPCBeacon` module. Hence I changed `CNPCBeacon.cc` as:-

```
cModule* parentmod = getParentModule();
cModule* grantParentmod = parentmod->getParentModule();
cModule* udpmod;
for (cSubModIterator iter(*grantParentmod); !iter.end(); iter++)
{
    //EV<<"get the modulde "<< iter()->getFullName()<<endl;
    if (strcmp(iter()->getFullName(), "udpApp[0]") == 0)
    {
        udpmod = iter();
        break;
    }
}
cPar& startTime = udpmod->par("startTime");
cPar& stopTime = udpmod->par("stopTime");
```

And I am successfully able to receive the values of `startTime` and `stopTime`. However I want to change these value in current module, which is resulting in an error by following code:

```
udpmod->par("startTime").setDoubleValue(4.2);
```

Can anybody please suggest me a way to change it at run time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declaring your parameter as `volatile` should solve your problem. But for future reference I'll provide further explanation below

---

**[`Volatile` vs. non-volatile](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec156):**

Here it depends how you want to use this parameter. Mainly via the `.ini` file you have two types of parameters: `volatile` and `non-volatile`.

`volatile` parameters are read every time during your run. That woule be helpful if you want this parameter to be generated by a built-in function, for example, `uniform(0,10)` each time this volatile parameter will get a different value.

On the other hand `non-volatile` parameters are read just one, as they don't change from run to run.

Using the `volatile` type parameter does not give you full flexibility, in the sense that your parameter value will always fall with in a range predefined in the `.ini`

---

**Dynamic Variable (parameter) Reassignment:**

Instead what you could do is use a more robust approach, and re-define the variable which stores the value from that module parameter each time you have to do so.

For example in your case you could do the following:

```
varHoldingStartTime = par("startTime").doubleValue();
varHoldingStartTime = 4.2;
```

This way the actual value will change internally without reflecting to your run.

---

**Parameter Studies:**

Alternatively if you want this change of the parameter to be applied to multiple runs you could use the advanced built-in approach provided by OMNeT++ which allows you to perform [Parameter Studies](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec341).

I have explained here how Parameter Studies work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30572095/4786271 and also here how it can be achieved with constraints etc: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29622426/4786271

If none of the approaches suggested by me fit your case, answers to this question altogether might solve your problem: [How to change configuration of network during simulation in OMNeT++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613536/how-to-change-configuration-of-network-during-simulation-in-omnet/29622426#29622426)

---

**EDIT:** extending the answer to roughly explain [handleParameterChange()](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/usman.html#sec156)

I have not used `handleParameterChange()` before as well, but from what can I see this function provides a **watchdog** functionality to the module which utilizes it.

To activate this functionality first the `void handleParameterChange(const char *parameterName);` has to be re-defined.

In essence what it seems to do is the following:

Assume we have two modules `moduleA` and `moduleB` and `moduleB` has parameter `parB`. `moduleA` changes the `parB` and when that happens, `moduleB` reacts to this change based on the behaviour defined in:

```
moduleB::handleParameterChange(parB);
```

The behaviour could be re-reading the original value for `parB` from the `.ini` etc.

Comment: Wow... that's what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for this. However would you please also add the functionality of `handleParameterChange()` . I read about it from OMNeT manual section 4.5.5 but  I am not able to grasp the concept properly. My first though was to use `handleParameterChange()` for this situation. Thanks a lot for this.

Comment: hi @user4786271 , I updated the parameter as : `udpmod->par("startTime").setDoubleValue(varHoldingStartTime);              udpmod->par("stopTime").setDoubleValue(varGoldingStopTime);` Parameter set perfectly and checked but the udpApp module won't start at the start time. So I tried to create a object to initiate udpApp from CNPCBeacon as `UDPBasicApp* udpBasicMod = dynamic_cast<UDPBasicApp*>(udpmod);
udpBasicMod->scheduleStart((simttime_t)varHoldingStartTime);`. But it won't initiate the udpBasicMod. Can you please tell me how can I initiate a module from other sub module. Thanks

Comment: @Peter that is a separate question and would be against the purpose of SO to answer it here in a comment. Please post it as a new question, and then I can see if I can help. Then maybe it helps to the others for future reference :)

Comment: hi @user4786271, okey, I will set it as a new question as you suggested. Thanks